Bourbaki definitions of projective and inductive limits
I'm currently reading the Bourbaki book on set theory (in French, so please excuse me if I mistranslate).
I am struggling to understand the concepts of projective and inductive limits (or systems), and I was wondering if someone could give me some insight to help me understand it. (I also saw that these are used in general topology in order to define limits in that context as well).
One of the difficulties I'm having is that I cannot see the relationship between this notion of limit and the one that's commonly used in analysis courses (so on metric spaces, I think).
I have unfortunately not studied category theory yet, but to my understanding, the book takes a metamathematical approach to construct these things, so I think it should theoretically not be a problem.

Don't look for a connection to the limits from real analysis, they're not related (per se). This is the categorial notion of limit, and picking up a book on category theory and reading about limits and colimits might be a good idea.

@BenSteffan There is a relationship (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9951/limits-in-category-theory-and-analysis), but you are right: At the moment the OP should focus on the categorical concecpt.
